# Regex doesn't stop evaluating after matching with first rule with OR operator

Tags: python, regex

i am having  issues with regex matching in python i have a string as follows:

```
test_str = ("ICD : 12123575.007787. 098.3,\n"
    "193235.1, 132534.0, 17707.1,1777029, V40‚0, 5612356,9899\n")
```

my regular expression has two main groups bind together with `|` and that regular expression is as follows:

```
  regex =   r"((?<=ICD\s:\s).*\n.*)|((?<=ICD\s).*)"
```

Lets call them `(A | B)`. Where `A = ((?<=ICD\s:\s).*\n.*)` and `B = ((?<=ICD\s).*)`. According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `|` works in a way where if `A` is matched it won't go further with `B`.

Now my problem is that when i use above mentioned regular expression `test_str`. It matches for `B` but not for `A`. But if i search with regular expression `A` only *(i.e. `((?<=ICD\s:\s).*\n.*)`)*, then the `test_string` is matched with the regular expression `A`. So my question is that why with `A|B` regular expression is not matched with group `A` and stopped. Following is my python code:

```
import re

regex = r"((?<=ICD\s:\s).*\n.*)|((?<=ICD\s).*)"

test_str = ("ICD : 12123575.007787. 098.3,\n"
    "193235.1, 132534.0, 17707.1,1777029, V40‚0, 5612356,9899\n")

matches = re.search(regex, test_str)
if matches:
    print ("Match was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(
        start = matches.start(), 
        end = matches.end(), 
        match = matches.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(matches.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(
            groupNum = groupNum, 
            start = matches.start(groupNum), 
            end = matches.end(groupNum), 
            group = matches.group(groupNum)))
```

output:

```
Match was found at 4-29: : 12123575.007787. 098.3,
Group 1 found at -1--1: None
Group 2 found at 4-29: : 12123575.007787. 098.3,
```

[Python Fiddle](https://repl.it/KShc/2)

Sorry if you are not able to understand. I don't know why `Group 1 found at -1--1: None` is not matched. Let me know what could be the reason if you understood it.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the fact that you're doing `(A)|(B)` rather than `(A|B)`? `()` is a capturing group, so it would make sense to capture the whole thing, I think.

Comment: If you remove the lookbehind, the whole thing works as expected regex = r"(?:(?:ICD)(\s:\s.*\n.*))|(?:(?:ICD)(\s.*))" https://repl.it/KShc/3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because regex searches for a match from left to right, and the right half of the regex matches earlier. This is because the left expression has a longer lookbehind: `(?<=ICD\s:\s)` requires two more characters than `(?<=ICD\s)`.

```
test_str = "ICD : 12123575.007787. 098.3,\n"
#                 ^ left half of the regex matches here
#               ^ right half of the regex matches here
```

To put it another way, your regexes are essentially like `(?<=.{3})` and `(?<=.)`. If you tried `re.search(r'(?<=.{3})|(?<=.)', some_text)`, it's clear that the right side of the regex would match first, because its lookbehind is shorter.

---

You can fix this by preventing the right half of the regex from matching too early by adding a negative lookahead:

```
regex = r"((?<=ICD\s:\s).*\n.*)|((?<=ICD\s)(?!:\s).*)"
#                                          ^^^^^^^

test_str = "ICD : 12123575.007787. 098.3,\n"
#                 ^ left half of the regex matches here
#          right half of the regex matches doesn't match at all
```

Comment: Thanks mate for making me understand about negative lookahead. Its working now